# Terraform is complaining that azurerm_linux_function_app cannot support a storage_account block, but the docs state otherwise

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions, azure-storage, terraform-provider-azure

My Azure file contains a Linux function and a storage account (as necessary for functions). I am trying to add a storage_account block, [which is defined in the docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_function_app#storage_account), but I am getting an error which says that storage_account blocks are not supported here.

```
# Configure the Azure provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.0.2"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "ytapp" {
  name     = "ytapp"
  location = "eastus"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "ytapp-storage" {
  name                     = "ytappstorage"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.ytapp.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.ytapp.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  access_tier              = "Hot"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share" "ytapp-storage-share" {
  name                 = "ytapp-storage-share"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.ytapp-storage
  quota                = 300

  acl {
    id = "redacted"

    access_policy {
      permissions = "rwdl"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "ytapp-service-plan" {
  name                = "ytapp-service-plan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.ytapp.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.ytapp.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "Y1"
}

resource "azurerm_application_insights" "ytapp-insights" {
  name                = "ytapp-insights"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.ytapp.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.ytapp
  application_type    = "other"
  retention_in_days   = 90
  disable_ip_masking  = false
}

output "instrumentation_key" {
  value = azurerm_application_insights.ytapp-insights.instrumentation_key
}

output "app_id" {
  value = azurerm_application_insights.ytapp-insights.app_id
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "ytapp-functions" {
  name                       = "ytapp-functions"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.ytapp.name
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.ytapp.location
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.ytapp-service-plan.id

  site_config {
    application_insights_key = azurerm_application_insights.ytapp-insights.instrumentation_key
  }

  storage_account {
    access_key   = azurerm_storage_account.ytapp-storage.primary_access_key
    account_name = azurerm_storage_account.ytapp-storage.name
    name         = "ytapp-data"
    share_name   = azurerm_storage_share.ytapp-storage-share.name
    type         = "AzureFiles"
    mount_path   = "/videos"
  }
}
```

```
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on main.tf line 80, in resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "ytapp-functions":
│   80:   storage_account {
│
│ Blocks of type "storage_account" are not expected here.
```

I tried Googling, ChatGPT, I tried moving the block inside of the site_config (at ChatGPT's suggestion). I really want to keep this block so that I can mount a file store to my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you include the `storage_account` block in your terraform code, you must also include `storage_account_name`. The `storage_account_access_key` argument is optional because it is already provided in the `storage_account` block. There will be a conflict if you do not include this.

And, as @Marcin pointed out, always use the most recently released provider versions because some arguments and attribute references are not supported in earlier versions.

*I modified your code as below and it worked for me as expected.*

**`main.tf`:**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.61.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "ytapp" {
  name     = "ytapp"
  location = "eastus"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "ytapp-storage" {
  name                     = "ytappstorage"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.ytapp.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.ytapp.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  access_tier              = "Hot"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_share" "ytapp-storage-share" {
  name                 = "ytapp-storage-share"
  storage_account_name = "ytappstorage"
 quota                = 300
  acl {
    id = "redacted"
    access_policy {
      permissions = "rwdl"
    }
  }
}
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "ytapp-service-plan" {
  name                = "ytapp-service-plan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.ytapp.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.ytapp.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "Y1"
}
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "ytapp-insights" {
  name                = "ytapp-insights"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.ytapp.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.ytapp.name
  application_type    = "other"
  retention_in_days   = 90
  disable_ip_masking  = false
}
output "app_id" {
  value = azurerm_application_insights.ytapp-insights.app_id
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "ytapp-functions" {
  name                       = "ytapp-functions"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.ytapp.name
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.ytapp.location
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.ytapp-service-plan.id
  site_config {
    application_insights_key = azurerm_application_insights.ytapp-insights.instrumentation_key
  }
  storage_account_name = "ytappstorage"
  storage_account {
    name = "MynewShare"
    type = "AzureFiles"
    account_name = azurerm_storage_account.ytapp-storage.name
    share_name = "sharedaccount"
    access_key = azurerm_storage_account.ytapp-storage.primary_access_key
    mount_path = "/directory"
  }   
}
```

`terraform init`:

[image]

`terraform plan`:

[image]

`terraform apply`:

[image]

*The storage account has been successfully linked to the* `linux_function_app`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's funny, I originally had the storage_account_name attribute but that was one of the first things I tried removing when I initially encountered the error, thinking it might just be duplicate information and that you should provide either / or.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **upgrade** your azure provider. Your current version `3.0.2` is very old. Current version is `3.61.0`.

```
terraform init -upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks! I copied this from [their docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/azure-get-started/azure-build) so I didn't realize it was out of date :)